# Как найти в тексте строго трехзначное число?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно определять из текста строго трехзначное число.

Пробовал:

```
re.findall('[0-9]{3}', '1234')
```

Выводит "123", а мне нужно, чтобы ничего не выводило, т.к. число четырехзначное.

Либо, если текст такой "123-123", то нужно, чтобы тоже ничего не выводило.

Какой способ посоветуете?

Comment: Для первой части достаточно использовать `\b`: `print(re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\b', '1234 123 5555'))`, а вот с `123-123` сложнее. А в чем задание? Почему могут быть и так, и такие числа?

Comment: *Мне нужно определять из текста строго трехзначное число .. если текст такой "123-123", то нужно, чтобы тоже ничего не выводило* Чётко определите. чем должна быть ограничена требуемая последовательность.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Решением будет такое выражение, которое найдёт 3-значное число между пробельными символами или началом/концом строки (т.е. с использованием **пробельных границ**):

```py
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[0-9]{3}(?!\S)', '987 6781 t 444 t 1234 zzz 453')
# => ['987', '444', '453']
```

Хотя, в таком случае, зачем нужны регулярные выражения?

```py
[x for x in '987 6781 t 444 t 1234 zzz 453'.split() if len(x) == 3 and all(z.isdigit() for z in x)]
# => ['987', '444', '453']
```

Если границы не пробельные, а....

- дефисно-цифровые: `re.findall(r'(?<![-\d])[0-9]{3}(?![-\d])', '-987 123-123 444- t 1234 zzz 453')` => `['453']`
- не между цифрами или цифрой+дефисом или дефисом+цифрой: `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d-)[0-9]{3}(?!-?\d)', '-987 123-123 444- t 1234 zzz 453')` => `['987', '444', '453']`

**Дополнительно**

Очень часто пользователи, спрашивающие, как проверить строку на строгое соответсвтие шаблону, имеют в виду:

- Полное соответствие строки шаблону: `bool(re.fullmatch(r'[0-9]{3}', '123'))` => `True` (ещё `re.match(r'[0-9]{3}$', '123')` и `re.search(r'^[0-9]{3}$', '123')`)
- Не между буквами/цифрами/знаком подчёркивания: `re.findall(r'\b[0-9]{3}\b', '123,456,12345,b123,876_')` => `['123', '456']`
- Не между буквами/цифрами (исключая знак подчёркивания): `re.findall(r'(?<![^\W_])[0-9]{3}(?![^\W_])', '123,456,12345,b123,876_')` => `['123', '456', '876']`
- Не в дробных числах: `re.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?<!\d[.,])[0-9]{3}(?![.,]?\d)', '987.564 123-123 444,1234--453.')` => `['123', '123', '453']` (удалите либо символ точки, либо запятой по вашему усмотрению).

Answer (score 4):

Пример: [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rl8t1Q/1)

```
(?:(?<=[^\w-])|(?<=^))\d{3}(?:(?=[^\w-])|(?=$))
```

Устанавливаем границы самостоятельно. Как в комментариях указали - `\b` указывает на границы слова, здесь определяем границы слова самостоятельно.
`(?<=[^\w-])|(?<=^)` - позитивный просмотр назад, либо все символы, кроме цифр, букв, нижнего подчеркивания и тире, либо начало строки. Далее захват 3 цифр, после чего аналогично построенный позитивный просмотр вперед. В случае, если нужно будет ограничить символы, после которых не должен быть захват 3х цифр, прописывать как раз в этих группах.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, как-то так:

```
re.findall('\b(?<!-)[0-9]{3}(?!-)\b', '1234')
```